# raising an exception if a folder doesn't exist pathlib python

Tags: python, class, pathlib

I'm working on automating some record keeping and am trying to create a `class` that represents the folders where the records are stored.

I want to raise an exception, or make the `class` creation fail if the folder doesn't exit

```py
from pathlib import Path

class Records:
    
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location
         if Path(f'{self.location}').exists:
            pass
         else:
            print('No folder exists at the location specified')

a = Records('path\\to\\a\\dir')
b = Records('not\\a\\real\\dir')

print(a.location)
print(b.location)
```

I have tested the above with various permutations and I've tried `try:except` blocks `b` is still created as a Records object even though the folder doesn't exist.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that prevents the object creation. What is your expectation?

Comment: I'd like the creator to fail if the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: exists is a method. you should call it : Path(f'{self.location}').exists()

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either, the object creating still completes.

Comment: add raise FileNotFoundError() after the print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [is_dir](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir) instead of exists if you want to check specifically for a folder. Either way, you should add brackets to call it.
Then, as Emmanuel said, if you want the class creation to fail, you can raise an error. Here a FileNotFound error could be a good candidate :

```
class Records:

    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location
        if Path(f'{self.location}').is_dir(): # don't forget ()
            pass
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError('No folder exists at the location specified')
```

Afterwards you have several ways to handle it in your code. If you want the code to crash on class creation failure, just call it.

```
b = Records('not\\a\\real\\dir') # causes program to crash with a FileNotFoundError
```

If you want your program to continue, do

```
try:
     b = Records('not\\a\\real\\dir')
except FileNotFoundError:
     print("The class could not be created as the specified folder does not exist")

# do other stuff here, calling b will fail though
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to raise an exception

To raise an exception you must explicitely call `raise`.

> or make the class creation fail if the folder doesn't exit

Please be more specific, as *fail* is not precise enough. Raising an exception will cause your program to stop if not caught.

Comment: Thanks for the input. @ozs answered the question for me. If you know a tutorial or resources that might help me phrase the question with the right specifics then that would be great. Either way. Thanks a million.